# rails javascript assets conflicts

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, lazy-high-charts, bootstrap-wysihtml5

Currently I work with two gems whitch provide javascript assets. These two assets are conflicting with each other.

In my case it's the [lazy_high_charts](https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts) gem and the [bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails](https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails) gem.

I have both in my current project. First I had only the bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails gem for some textboxes. Yesterday I added the lazy_high_charts gem into my project for a dashboard.

I have wysiwyg text boxes in multiple places inside my application. For the dashboard I created a new controller Dashboard with an index action.

After I added the lazy_high_charts_gem and required the javascript files inside my application.js manifest file all wysiwyg editors in my text boxes across the whole project disappeared. As soon as I removed the lazy_high_charts javascript requirements from my application.js file the wysiwyg editors were back.

**First attempt**
My first attempt to fix this was to change the order of my javascript requirements from:

**application.js**

```
//= require bootstrap-wysihtml5
//= require bootstrap-wysihtml5/locales/de-DE
//= require highcharts/highcharts                                                           
//= require highcharts/highcharts-more                                                         
//= require highcharts/highstock
```

to:
**application.js**

```
//= require highcharts/highcharts                                                           
//= require highcharts/highcharts-more                                                         
//= require highcharts/highstock
//= require bootstrap-wysihtml5
//= require bootstrap-wysihtml5/locales/de-DE
```

But that changed nothing.

**Second attempt**

My second attempt to fix this was to require the lazy_high_charts javascript files inside the dashboard.js file.

**application.js**

```
//= require bootstrap-wysihtml5
//= require bootstrap-wysihtml5/locales/de-DE
```

**dashboard.js**

```
//= require highcharts/highcharts                                                           
//= require highcharts/highcharts-more                                                         
//= require highcharts/highstock
```

But the problem with this attempt was that after precompiling all the assets the javascript files are compiled into this one big javascript file and my wysiwyg editors stopped again.

**My third idea is the following:**
For my dashboard I could create an own asset folder and an own manifest file for my dashboard controller. In it's javascript manifest I could require the lazy_high_charts javascript files. At the bottom of my dashboard/index.html.erb view file I could load the javascript manifest with

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "dashboard" %>
```

That would solve the problem at the moment. But when I need an view with a high charts graph and a wysiwyg text box I ran into the same problem once again.

Therefore I ask me if there isn't a better solution which will stop the conflict of both gems and will allow me to use both in the same view.

Comment: Try to be a bit more clear.  It seems like you wrote this in a haste and rambled a bit.  It is hard for people to help you when it's hard for them to follow your 'question.'

Comment: Sorry that I was not clear enough. I changed my question and hope that it'S clearer now. My English is not the best, I think that was more the problem. Is it now clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

I use the full [highcharts gem](https://github.com/PerfectlyNormal/highcharts-rails) with [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/applications.html) which is pretty similar to bootstrap and I haven't found any compatibility issues...

Probably not the answer you're looking for, but maybe a good option!